# Updating a mappin reference in EF 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, setter

To begin with i'm not really sure if it's called a mappin reference. However I have two tables with important information and one table in between them. It is as follows:

```
  CREATE TABLE Customer (
      ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), -- PK
      Number VARHCAR(255) NOT NULL,
  ) ....

  CREATE TABLE Category (
      ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), -- PK
      Type INT NOT NULL,             -- Defines the different category types
      Number VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ) ....

  CREATE TABLE CustomerCategories (
      FK_Customer INT NOT NULL, -- References customer
      FK_Category INT NOT NULL  -- References category
  ) .... unique (FK_Customer, FK_Category)
```

In this model, a customer can have several categories (as long as the category.Type are different).

IT might look like this:

**Customer:**

ID| Number

3 | 10000

**Category:**

ID|Type|Number |Name

52| 1 | PRIO_H |High

53| 2 | REG | Region South

**CustomerCategories:**

FK_Customer | FK_Category

3 | 52

3 | 53

In my c# application I put all the categories in a grid, where the users can change the different category types based on a drop down list.

I use EF4 Object context.

In my application my Customer model is like this

```
  interface ICustomer 
  {
     int ID {get;}
     string Number {get;}
     Category Priority {get;set;}
     Category Region {get;set;}
  }
```

And my implementation

```
 partial class Customer : ICustomer
 {
     ID... // Not important right now
     Number... // Not important right now
     public Category Priority
     {
         get { return this.CustomerCategory.Where(c => c.Type == 1).Select(c2 => c2.Category).FirstOrDefault<Category>(); } // The getter works
         set {}
     }
 }
```

I have problems setting the value, I have tried

```
set {this.CustomerCategory.Where(c => c.Type == 1).Select(c2 => c2.Category) == value;}
```

And this one says : Cannot convert type Model.Category to IEnumerable

So I have tried to explicitly select the value by doing

```
set {this.CustomerCategory.Where(c => c.Type == 1).Select(c2 => c2.Category).FirstOrDefault<Category>() == value;}
```

And now it says : Left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer.

Does anyone know how to update such references using EF4 and object context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to assign a value to result of IQueryable.
this should work:

```
set 
{
    var cc = context.CustomerCategory.Where(c => c.Type == 1).FirstOrDefault();
    if (cc!=null)
    {
        cc.Category =  value;
        //or cc.CategoryId = value.Id; if you have foreign keys exposed
        //context.SaveChanges(); if you need changes saved in the database immediately.
    }
}
```